# Keyboard shows then immediately hides itself when showing MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap app using Cordova 2.2 for IOS. I am experiencing some bizarre behavior when calling out to a native obj-c plugin I have written to show the MFMessageComposeViewController.

The setup is very simple - I have a tap event attached to a UI element, that when pressed, will make a call to my PhoneGap plugin, pass with it a number and a text message, then show the MFMessageComposeViewController with the parameters pre-populated.

My javascript looks like this:

```
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){ 

    $(".theButton").tap(function(){     

        cordova.exec(function(){}, function() {}, "PhoneGapSms", "SendSms", [db.getItem("profile_sms"), db.getItem("profile_emergency")]);

    }); 
});
```

And my obj-c code looks like this:

```
- (void)SendSms:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

    CDVInvokedUrlCommand* myCommand = command;

    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    NSString* body = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* toRecipientsString = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];

        if(body != nil)
            picker.body = body;

        if(toRecipientsString != nil)
            [picker setRecipients:[ toRecipientsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];


    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self.viewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];


    [picker release];

}
```

So, all in all, very simple stuff.

**My Problem is this:**

When my iPhone is **plugged into my Mac and the app is run from XCode**, the Message Composer overlay appears great, with my values pre-populated. Image below demonstrating the SMS interface appears fine while plugged into XCode:

[image]

When my iPhone is **unplugged from my Mac, and the app is run from the spring board**, the Overlay slides up, the keyboard begins to slide up, **then immediately slides down** - making it impossible to type or send the message. This is what it looks like when not attached to the Mac/Xcode - the keyboard begins to slide up then immediately slides down (~ < 1 sec) leaving the following interface:

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out what would cause the keyboard to hide when not running from XCode, but work perfectly well when it is.

Is there any way to 'force' the keyboard to display, or possibly put the whole modalviewcontroller as first responder in some form or fashion?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

**Edit:**

The keyboard WILL appear again if you click in the contact area

Answer (score 3):

You must add `MessageUI.framework` to your Xcode project and include a

`#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` in your header file.

try this code may be its helpful to you..

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
//[self becomeFirstResponder];//try picker also instead of self
```

Also Refer this bellow tutorial and also check demo..

1. [new-tutorial-developing-and-architecting-a-phonegap-application](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/11/new-tutorial-developing-and-architecting-a-phonegap-application/)
2. [SMSComposer](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer)

i hope this help you...

Comment: @Evan try this answer and post comment if any query.. hope you got it.. :)

Comment: @Evan used this tutorial dude?? also just change the flow from viewcontroller to navigationcontroller dude...

Comment: I don't think he'd be able to instantiate a MFMessageComposeViewController if he wasn't importing the MessageUI framework...

Comment: @Evan also see this plugin dude which used in many field i think above links is best and also this one with one option from which you can get some idea dude..  https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins .. just change some code and it will work fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered these symptoms with a Sencha Touch 2.2 and Cordova 2.6.0 setup (specifically, iOS 6+ devices).

The issue was with the web framework stealing focus away from the native SMS Composer modal, typically occurring after the first SMS Composer modal had been successfully displayed and closed.

A `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` call once the event had been fired (or `event.stopEvent()` in Sencha land) resolved this.

Hope this helps,

-James

Comment: This is brilliant sleuthing and a working solution. I can confirm it works for Sencha Touch 2.2.0 and Cordova 2.3.0 on iOS 6+. How did you come about to this answer? I was not even sure how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: The most likely culprit, without seeing your code, is that your parent (presenting) view controller may have an action in its `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` that is affecting who has the "first" responder.  These methods get called when presenting a view controller modally.  It may be behaving differently on the simulator than the device due to timing - often really close timing conditions are different on the ARM device and the i386 processor.

**Second**: Does anywhere in your app register for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` or the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`?  If so, put breakpoints in the methods that are called as a result - it's possible some other controller in your view hierarchy is interfering with this one.

To answer your question...

> Is there any way to 'force' the keyboard to display, or possibly put the whole modalviewcontroller as first responder in some form or fashion?

No to both.  The only way to make the keyboard display is to call the `becomeFirstResponder` method of the input view.  Since Apple doesn't expose the text view, you cannot send it messages.  Setting the `modalViewController` as first responder would be setting the wrong object.

Comment: If none of that resolves your issue, post more code for us to see!

Comment: Also, you can see on this code here - https://github.com/grant/phonegap-plugins/commit/db93ea6db5eb38beddbda0d33975fbec63154cd6 there's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same type of issue But Not Sure it will Solve your problem or not Just Have a Look on the Following Links :
 1. http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/keyboard_is_not_triggerd_in_my_ios_build
 2. https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/31

If its not Solving your issue then you can Download the Sample code [Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer).

Link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer